# Python not writing all rows of data from MS SQL Stored Procedure to CSV

Tags: python, sql-server

I am working on a script that will execute a MS SQL stored procedure and write each row to a CSV. It is outputting all but about the last ten rows of the SELECT statement, for the last row it does write it only has data in the first two columns.

```
# Importing the required libaries
import pypyodbc
import csv
import win32com.client as win32
import time

# Setting up the Connection to the SQL Server
cnxn = pypyodbc.connect("Driver= {SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                    "Server=sql2012;"
                    "Database=Client;"
                    "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
data = cursor.execute("EXEC usp_rpt_QuestionFile") #Running the SP and housing the data 
headers = [tuple[0] for tuple in data.description] # Getting the field names out of the SP
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d") # Storing the current date
path = "Y:\Client Files\Client\Perpetual\Questions\Client QuestionsTest"+timestr+".csv" # Where the file will be saved
f = csv.writer(open(path, "wb"), delimiter=",")
f.writerow(headers) #Writing the field names as the first row to the CSV
for row in data: #Appending the data to the file
    f.writerow(row)


#Sending the email and attachment
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'email@email.com'
mail.Subject = 'Subject'
mail.body = ''
attachment1 = path
mail.Attachments.Add(Source=attachment1)
mail.send
```

Comment: When printing `row` to screen or something, do all expected rows returned from the SP present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is data missing from the output file on the Y drive or is it only missing from the emailed copy? If the latter, it looks like you need to close your output file so that the buffer is flushed before you copy it into the email.
Best way is to use a `with` statement:

```
with open(path, "wb") as f:
    wtr = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
    wtr.writerow(headers) #Writing the field names as the first row to the CSV
    wtr.writerows(data)
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks.